# ASP.net viewstate links error

Tags: c#, asp.net

When the contents is placed inside the contentplaceholder, the behavior of the links are changed, I have to refresh the page to make the download links functional.  I also have to remove the form tag when I place the contentplaceholder. How do I fix the behavior of the links while having a contentplaceholder to reference my master page? (some code removed to shorten and privacy)

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain">

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head >
    <title></title>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <%--<form id="ThisForm" runat="server">--%>
    <div>

        <table style="width:100%;">
</table>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ContentPlaceHolders replace content in the page. A MasterPage is like a template you apply to a page. It holds all basic functionality and layout you want.

So when you create a page based on a MasterPage that page will use the Form and markup from the MasterPage as a basis. You just fill in the gaps (your ContentPlaceHolders).

You want to remove all that markup and only put what you need inside that ContentPlaceHolder.